# Selecting an element on the basis of other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select B element on the basis of A element i.e. when A's class becomes .activeLesson . B element should be selected. How should I do that?

```
<ul class="">
  <li>L4</li>
  <li>L5</li>
  <li class="lastChild">L5</li>
</ul>

<article class="active"></article>
```

While last li gets class 'lastchild' ( using some jquery ) I want to change article class from 'active' to 'inactive'

Does that make sense now?

Comment: I used this $('.lessonNavigation li:last-child.activeLesson'). But don't know how to select other element on the basis of this

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to get a javascript notification when a class value is changed is by using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which is not particularly cross browser yet (requires IE11 or greater to work in IE).  Other than that, you'd probably have to poll with a timer.  jQuery event handlers don't just suddenly fire when a class is added.  That's not how event handlers or jQuery objects work.  If I were you, I'd rethink the approach and have the code that changes the class, trigger a notification itself.

Comment: I see you're relatively new here on StackOverflow, so you probably should understand that questions with no HTML and no code and no good description of the actual goal where all are relevant to the question rarely attract very useful answers because there simply isn't enough context in order to offer a good showcase of solutions.

Comment: The goal seems pretty clear to me, why are you downvoting this. He wants to know how to select elementB when elementA's class changes to .activeLesson... it's tagged as jQuery.

Comment: @jshanley - what the verb "select" means is not clear without seeing the HTML.  How would you write code to "select" something without even knowing what type of HTML it was?  Besides, unless IE 11 or greater is OK so mutation observers can be used, this question is going to need a different type of solution than the OP asked for so greater context will be required in order to help with that.  If the OP wants to stick with the question as is, then the answer is MutationObserver that doesn't work in IE below IE11 and other than that, there is no answer.

Comment: @jshanley - you might also notice that nobody is rushing to provide an answer.  That is generally because not enough information is provided in the question for people to offer helpful advice.  Show the HTML.  Show the code you've tried or options you've researched.  As the guidelines for SO clearly state, you should show the research that you've done and where you got stuck before asking the question.  This question shows none of that and offers no detail to offer other types of solutions to the overall problem.  How difficult would it be to trigger an even in the code that adds the class?

Comment: @user2854447 - are you OK with a solution that works only in the latest versions of browsers and for IE requires IE11 or greater?  If not, then there is no solution as you've asked the question because older versions of IE do not have the capability to trigger a javascript event when a class name is changed.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just because a question doesn't have a simple cross-browser solution doesn't mean it's a bad question. Since you're suggesting 'MutationObserver' you obviously get what he's trying to do, and lots of other people must have wanted to do it too which is why MutationObserver exists in the first place. It is okay to ask questions here that don't have simple answers or relate to things that are not currently possible to do.

Comment: @jshanley - I didn't say it was a bad question.  I said it was lacking details which would attract more solutions and I'm trying to explain that to the OP who is obviously new here.  I don't know why you're condemning me here.  I've offered more helpful info than anyone while trying to get the OP to disclose more info which might allow people to provide more options.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wasn't trying to condemn you, I just thought people were being kinda harsh. As it turns out, he was asking a completely different question than what we had in mind, so you're right it was just unclear.

Comment: I've updated question. Can anybody help now or guide me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do it right after the other code?

```
// adds the class 'lastChild' to the last li
$('li').last().addClass('lastChild')
// switches article from .active to .inactive
$('article').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive')
```

Comment: Thanks jshanley
But I want 'As last child of li gets some class ('lastchild') using jQuery article should get some class 'inactive. As 'lastchild' class get removed 'inactive' should also get removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `setInterval` work for you.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('li').is('.lastChild')) {
        $('article').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('article').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Here, the function runs every second. The function in turn checks the `<li>` for `lastChild` class and if it is present, it adds inactive and removes active class.

It does the vice-versa if the `<li>` doesn't have the `.lastChild` class

Comment: Is that necessary to use setInterval?